# NotificationBanner swift 3.x support

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to use NotificationBanner library (https://github.com/Daltron/NotificationBanner) but does not work with swift 3.3.

I'm trying   **pod 'NotificationBannerSwift', '1.4.5'** but no luck.

Here is the relevant pod file content:

```
  pod 'NotificationBannerSwift', '1.4.5'
  pod 'MarqueeLabel', '3.1.6'
  pod 'SnapKit', '3.2.0'
```

The MarqueeLabel and SnapKit are libraries used by the NotificationBannerSwift and I tried to lock them on versions that are compatible with swift 3.x

[image]

Comment: What do you mean `no luck`? Does it not install? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash at runtime?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - I've edited the post. Thanks

Comment: The latest version supports Swift 4.2, why not use that?

Comment: I should use latest swift version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use Swift 4.2 code in Swift 3.3. That's not going to work. Update your Xcode to Xcode 10 so that you can use Swift 4.2.

Comment: But the project is not supporting yet swift 4 (3.3). Can I use the library in that way to be compatible with swift 3.x?

Comment: Not if the only version of the library available to you is written in Swift 4.2, no. The versions of the language are completely incompatible with one another.

Comment: But that library was written in swift 3, so I used an older version(1.4.4) which was compatible with swift 3

Comment: No you didn't. I can _see_ from the screen shot that this is Swift 4.2.

Comment: The screenshot was taken during my attempts to make it to work(and in that moment was swift 4.2) I will update my screenshot later. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the post again. I added extra explain. I didn't worked from few years with ios until now and I thought that if a library have had support for swift 3.x I just need to specify that version and it will work...but that lib has another 2 dependencies which needs to be locked to specific version and still doesn't work

Comment: anyway, I think I should close this post since I got a response from their support: https://github.com/Daltron/NotificationBanner/issues/142

Comment: If you got an answer about this particular library that might help others, you can answer your own question!

Comment: Yes, but the answer is negative and no support is provided for swift 3. And it is time for me to migrate to swift 4